# IE8 Borders & Padding - Not rendering like IE7 and other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, doctype

IE8 not rendering padding & borders properly when doctype is ste to strict. Any suggestions? With doctype set to loose, the borders and padding are okay, but other bigger problems beyond CSS appear, so we're sticking w/ strict. Any suggestions on where to start to resolve border & padding style discrepancies?

Comment: You'll increase the chances of a definitive answer if you provide some source code, otherwise I have no clue what you're dealing with.

Comment: I know --- i wish I could include a link, but it's an Intranet. I am hoping someone has seen something similar before and might have some ideas of what I might look at...  But thank you for the comment anyway!

Comment: Make sure they there are no HTML comments above the doctype, IE will not apply the doctype switch in that case. Could you atleast share the exact doctype that you are using?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

For now I'm using the meta tag to emulate IE7 (compatibility mode) -- I feel like it shouldn't be necessary though, like it's a hack or cop-out.

Answer (score 1):

Since IE 8 is the first Microsoft browser to try to follow standards, it's likely your page isn't standard compliant which is why it won't render properly in strict doctype.

If you want to use a strict doctype you should probably [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) it first

If you want IE 8 to behave like IE 7 try adding this to `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

which puts IE 8 in IE 7 compatibility mode.  Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i honestly think this "IE8 as IE7" fix is introducing yet another quirksmode, but digress.  betsy, are you applying this padding or margin to the <html> or <body> tags?  if so, then you should actually apply that css to an element within the <body> itself.  for some reason, IE8 does not recognize those styles applied to those elements.